# jni.h | как правильно инициализировать JNIEnv

Tags: c++, jni

Как правильно инициализировать JNIEnv что-бы не было краша? (код)

```
#include "pch.h"
    #include "jni.h"
    #include <iostream>

    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    HANDLE jvmHandle;
    FARPROC func_JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

    void init() {
        AllocConsole();
        freopen_s((FILE**)stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        std::cout << "This works" << std::endl;

        typedef jint(JNICALL* GetCreatedJavaVMs)(JavaVM**, jsize, jsize*);
        GetCreatedJavaVMs jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs;
        jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs = (GetCreatedJavaVMs)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(
            TEXT("jvm.dll")), "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs");



        std::cout << "CreatedJavaVMs: " << jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs << std::endl;

        jint ver = env->GetVersion(); // Если убрать краша не будет

        std::cout << "JVM load succeeded: Version ";



    }

    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
        DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
        LPVOID lpReserved
    )
    {
        init();
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: Как минимум, экспортировать специальную функцию, которую должен будет вызвать клиент библиотеки.

Comment: я просил код.........